# How can I add HTTP headers in Cloudflare?

Tags: cloudflare, http-headers

I have a Cloudflare website and it is hosted on Cloudflare Pages, but I want to add HTTP headers to this website. There are a lot of DNS and HTTP related settings in Cloudflare. I am undecided which one to do.

My question is How can I add http headers in Cloudflare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps below to add HTTP headers in Cloudflare:

1. Select your website.
2. `Click Rules` from the left side menu.
3. `Click Transform Rules` in the menu that opens under `Rules`.
4. There are 4 different options in `Transform Rules`, but not in the menu, but in the page section, select `Modify Response Header` from this page section.
5. Press the `Create Rule` button.
6. In the first `Rule Name` section, type any name you want, just any importance to personalise it.
7. `When incoming requests match...` question, if you are going to add HTTP header to the whole site, click `All Incoming Requests` option, if you are going to select a specific page, select the 2nd option there and apply the filtering.
8. Press the `Set New Header` button to add the HTTP header under the Then section.
9. In the Set Static section, select the `Static` section and type the HTTP header you want to enter in the 2 boxes that appear.
10. Press `Save` and the HTTP header is now added.